# PHP Session Just one JSON value

Tags: php, json, session, oauth, google-oauth

I'm trying to set up Google OAuth for my website, but when reading my sessions from XDebug, I only have one named 'token', which contains the following json:

```
{"access_token":"ya29.Ci-IA6fojB-Q8EpBY1klxrJ-YmEPW66nn6uT5HDYiWcbuuqfPPBaCLkKbRhntkcfJg","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjgxMzIxMjcyNDliMjE3ZGVhYTczY2VmMzY4MDlmNWQ0YmE5YTY2ODMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDc3NDkzMTMxLCJleHAiOjE0Nzc0OTY3MzEsImF0X2hhc2giOiI3MWpTeGlVRzZBb3lsTFBubmZSaXJBIiwiYXVkIjoiMTAwNzI3NjY3NTMzNC1yczIycmtqamI4YXAxa3VkbGRiYmFkYmthc29zNWE4ZC5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwMDc5NTc2NzYxNzg3MjkwNzIwNCIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJhenAiOiIxMDA3Mjc2Njc1MzM0LXJzMjJya2pqYjhhcDFrdWRsZGJiYWRia2Fzb3M1YThkLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJtYXR0aGV3LmJldG9uQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.gbbEXfnnYR44qwEr_im9PMG9slhf014MHrvODmW7fZxmeTHCVhJgogP7GD4goqJHZxWc9CWYGdxwaqNnF9GJOCzdtd9zIzrixyAaHQizeAS5qNaxpMz_pM-NlsJLdSPOxtbkE6R_b1f2minkx0l1lyl0N23kOWt2j6asQ40N6Mv-AGZXHDjMwaNR2rMkZxe_7jy1vwYLC6UWWY6i0ngObRztp2XNZbIudlxzhmGU24TCVCkPcXQgzt2yitp98WnsoqswhniBFZHn7GtE_Fu7FcCRWZqtrXZMhxh0cNTSKQFpC-N4rX2eOR_e3fHyi-tZf0Rs2fOA-eUlDLlfgwPItg","refresh_token":"1\/3fK7kUyVLQEzmD1-xInEgki3sgcw79axalzldRznZq8","token_type":"Bearer","created":1477493130}
```

The session I was setting was called 'access_token' like so:

```
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

But when I do `isset($_SESSION['access_token']`, It returns false. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it normal for tokens to be set in this format?

My full code where the session is set (login.php): http://pastebin.com/F0S5fWyt
Where the session is checked (index.php): http://pastebin.com/YxCUpjFF

Comment: Unless it's in `core.php` you never `session_start()` in `login.php`.

Comment: If I remove `session_start()`, I just get `Undefined variable: _SESSION`.

Comment: You do not do a `start_session()` in `login.php` and you should

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. This hasn't fixed the JSON, but that might just be normal, I'll figure it out :D